# Maintain unique value in mongoose js not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have tried searching for the answer and here are the options that i have tried so far

```
email: {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email, required: true, index : {unique: true}}
email: {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email, required: true, unique: true},
```

And still i get the insertions with same email used into the database. Where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code that worked for me

```
email    : {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email, required: true,index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}},
```

Also remember that you need to restart the `mongodb` server.